# WP REST API - get custom taxonomies based on terms & filter

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, meta-query, wp-api, rest-api

I need to get the list of data's with taxonomy term property_category,based on this property_category having data's like apartment,house,office etc.For example localhost url given

```
http://192.168.0.101:8383/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/property_category
```

And also need to get the list of data's with taxonomy term property_type_category,based on this property_type_category having data's like rent,sale.

```
http://192.168.0.101:8383/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/property_type_category
```

And also one more question while filtering the data's with custom meta data's also not working.And i've added this custom code for filtering the data's.For example

**custom function**

```
add_filter('rest_query_vars', 'wp_rest_query_vars');
function wp_rest_query_vars($query_vars) {

    $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, array('meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_compare') );
    return $query_vars;

}
```

**Filter query**

```
http://192.168.0.101:8383/wp-json/wp/v2/properties?filter[meta_key]=property_bedrooms&filter[meta_value]=4&filter[meta_compare]=>=&filter[meta_key]=property_bathrooms&filter[meta_value]=4&filter[meta_compare]=>=
```

Answer (score 2):

Herewith find the below answer for my own question for the custom taxonomies based listing the categories

```
add_action( 'init', 'rest_custom_category_request', 25);
function rest_property_type_category_request(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['custom_category']->show_in_rest = true;
    $wp_taxonomies['custom_category']->rest_base = 'custom_category';
    $wp_taxonomies['custom_category']->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller';
}
```

Answer for the filter with custom meta key & values

```
add_filter('rest_query_vars', 'custom_rest_query_vars');
function custom_rest_query_vars($query_vars) {
    //print_r($query_vars);exit;
    $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, array('meta_key', 'meta_value', 'meta_compare') );
    return $query_vars;

}
```

But for the filter works with only one meta key & value not for two or more custom meta fields. I'm searching the solution for two or more custom meta fields filters. Hope you guys got solution for this problem help to me fix on this.

Thank you.